# Add an additional column into an inner array which is a calculation involved the it and the index before it

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array that looks a little like this:

```
var testArray = [
['Jan-2010', 867884],
['Feb-2010', 984655],
['Mar-2010', 322013],
['Apr-2010', -69417],
['May-2010', 310503],
['Jun-2010', 522857]];
```

I know that I can turn this into a table with index columns of 0 and 1, and have used console.table(testArray); to see it in action.

What I'm wondering is, how can I use a for loop to add a column (index of 2) which would be a calculation of the difference between the current amount, and the amount before.

The new data should look like this:

```
['Jan-2010', 867884, 867884] 
['Feb-2010', 984655, 116771] 
['Mar-2010', 322013, -662642]
['Apr-2010', -69417, -391430] 
['May-2010', 310503, 379920]
['Jun-2010', 522857, **212354**]
```

As an example, the figure in bold above, is a calculation of 522857 (index 5) - 310503 (index 4).

Comment: I am not able to understand that what exactly are you calculating?

Comment: please add a complete data set in literal notation and wanted result.

Comment: I have adjusted my question so that is it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have some other data in form of an array then below code is useful.

```js
var testArray = [
['Jan-2010', 867884],
['Feb-2010', 984655],
['Mar-2010', 322013],
['Apr-2010', -69417],
['May-2010', 310503],
['Jun-2010', 522857]
];

var currentAmount = [
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6];
for(let i=0;i<testArray.length;i++)
{
  testArray[i].push(testArray[i][1]-currentAmount[i])
}
console.log(testArray.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Also, how could we go about creating any given number of currentAmount items increasing in number, if we use testArray.length to fill it?

Comment: we obviously willl have the same length of testArray no matter how many items you have in currentAmount. If you could provide the calculation data and details of how you do it then may be I can provide a better solution.